# Configure Spark Worker stderr File

Tags: apache-spark, logging, stderr

How can to configure the stderr and stdout files size and rolling in Spark Workers?
Currently the stderr file gets larger and makes the disk run out of space.
I'm using Spark in Standalone Cluster mode.

Comment: Please explain on which mode are you running your application

Comment: Is it YARN cluster or Standalone cluster or Mesos?

Comment: it's a Standalone Cluster

Comment: In your spark installation directory, `conf/log4j.properties` will have the required configurations. Configuring the file appender with log rotation should help you.

Comment: I updated this file but didn't work. The stderr gets larger and larger

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143980/discussion-between-code-and-fattah-safa).

Comment: I updated the log4j to log only to log file with different name and it works. However, stderr and stdout are still be generated